# SQL Mirroring. Error while configuring SQL Server -The remote copy of database "Mirroring" does not exist

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

While configuration SQL server mirroring  I got below error.

I started SQL Server and Analysis services with same account on both servers. SQL server Agent service also started in both servers but reporting service was not installed in Principal server,will this conflict?

Firewall also stopped.

> Error:
>   An error occurred while starting mirroring.
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   Alter failed for Database 'Data Base'
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The remote copy of database "Data Base" does not exist. Check the database name and reissue the command. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1448)

**Following steps was used by me for Mirroring:**

1. Full and Transaction Log backup of Mirror DB have been taken from principal server.
2. Copied into Mirror server and Restored successfully with No Recovery option
3. Starting Mirroring into the Principal server
     Rightclick the DB--> click on Tasks--> click on Mirror--> Click on Config Security buttion--> Next... after creation of Endpoint finally click on start Mirroring. Here it's throwing error.

Comment: what is your database name on both servers

Comment: Both names are same